# Export google chrome history to file

Tags: google-chrome, history

Im trying to automate export chrome history to a file.
Ive learned google keep changing the mechanism for keeping history, while they used SQLLite i see in the version of chrome im using (88.X...) i cannot open the History file in that way,
all of my searches for this issue are not updated to this time, does anyone have information about this?

Comment: This [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-historybookmarks-t/dcoegfodcnjofhjfbhegcgjgapeichlf?hl=en) allows to export chrome's history to a file.